# Git: How to remove one commit from the main branch

Tags: git, version-control

I currently have one git branch and it is a flat git repo. I would like to remove one commit (not the latest one). May I know how to get this done?

I found what I wanna do is very similar to the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are single commands you can use, but one easy way is:

- `git stash` (if you don’t have a clean working directory)
- `git rebase -i A`
- delete the `pick X` line in your text editor, save, and quit

Answer (score 2):

**A possible alternative to removing the commit**

If you want or need to keep history straight, add a new commit on top whose job is to negate everything your bad commit (X) has brought. This operation is called "[revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert.html)" in git lingo.

```
git revert HEAD~2
```

would work in the case you're in, but you can also, rather than pointing to the commit relatively, do a `git log`, spot the bad commit, store its hash, and use it

```
git revert <commit-SHA1>
```

Afterwards, your tree will look like this

```
A---X---C'---D'---Y
```

where `Y` contains the exact inverse changes compared to `X`. **So the resulting codebase will be "as if you never did commit X", with the advantage of keeping track of the (canceled) operation.**

Comment: I am in favor of this solution if the purpose is to undo some changes. If the purpose of the removal is to get rid of credentials or secrets or big files, then a rebase is probably more appropriate (even though those secrets should be considered leaked anyway and must be recreated).

Comment: In particular I'm in favor of this solution because I see so many followup questions here on Stack Overflow where people have blindly followed advice on rebase and force-push and are now asking how to recover some commits and changes they lost when they didn't know what they were doing.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Fair enough. The reasons of the removal were not stated, but I fully agree **not** to go for a revert in case of confidential files.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this one and but the revert didn't get so well.

After the git revert I ran the git status I saw many files got removed. And I feel it may not work.

Comment: @Winston Hard to say why it "failed" without seeing the results, but revert is not destructive. You're able to go back to the state just before with `git reset --hard D'` where `D'` is the last commit of your graph here. Just look up its hash in your log.

Comment: @RomainValeri the reason why I am saying this is because I have commits updating the library and I also have commits updating the source code. The commits I wanna "remove" is the commits with the source code. After the revert actually I ran git status and saw that the library files get altered

Comment: @RomainValeri eventually I have to create a patch of that commit and apply the created patch. https://nithinbekal.com/posts/git-patch/ have more details

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

In the interactive editor, remove the line for the commit you want to remove and complete the interactive rebase operation (save and exit from the editor.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just type "git log"  and find the commitSHA of the commit which you want to remove.

Then type,

git revert commitSHA

```
      Or
```

git revert -n commitSHA, if you just want to revert that only modifies the working tree and the index.

Also, you can use git revert HEAD, inorder to revert the recent commit you had done.